# Show all legend levels in an R plotly figure legend

Tags: r, plotly, legend, levels

I'm trying to produce figures with a `legend` that corresponds to color-coded values.

Here's my data:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
                 start = c(1,3,5), end = c(2,4,6), width = 1, y = 0.1, label = rep(paste0("segment ",1:3),3),
                 value.range = c("7-8","2-3","4-5","1-2","5-6","3-4","6-7","8-9","6-7"))
```

Each `value.range` is then matched with a color:

```
colors.df <- data.frame(value.range = c("1-2","2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6","6-7","7-8","8-9"),
                        color = colorRampPalette(c("lightgray","darkred"))(8),
                        stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Setting `df$value.range` to a `factor` with `colors.df$value.range` as its levels:

```
df$value.range <- factor(df$value.range, levels = colors.df$value.range)
```

And then I'm producing a `list` of `plotly` figures, one for each `df$group`:

```
plot.list <- lapply(c("A","B","C"), function(g){
  plotly::plot_ly(dplyr::filter(df,group == g),showlegend=T) %>%
    plotly::add_bars(x =~ start,y =~ y,width =~ width,color =~ value.range, colors = colors.df$color) %>%
    plotly::layout(annotations = list(text = g, xref = "paper", yref = "paper", yanchor = "bottom", xanchor = "center", align = "center", x = 0.5, y = 1, showarrow = F), legend = list(x = 1, y = 0)) %>%
    plotly::layout(xaxis = list(title = NA, zeroline = F, tickangle = 45, range = c(-1, max(dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$end) + 1), tickvals = dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$start, ticktext = dplyr::filter(df,group == g)$label),
                   yaxis = list(title = NA, zeroline = F, showgrid = F, range = c(0,1), showticklabels = F)) %>%
    plotly::add_annotations(text = "log2(value)", xref = "paper", yref = "paper", x = 0.99, xanchor = "left", y = 0.5, yanchor = "top", legendtitle = T, showarrow = F)
})
```

Which gives:
[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see each figure's `legend` displays only the `value.range` values that are within its respective group.

My question is whether it is possible, and how, to make each `legend` display all values of `value.range` (i.e., everything in `colors.df`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered combining the plots using subplot function? The combined plots would have one legend with all of the values.

```
plotly::subplot(plot.list)
```

Comment: I did, and it comes out a bit messy with each figure having its own legend hence I thought of adding a condition to the `lapply` to add the legend only for group == "C". But then ran into the issue described in my post.

Comment: It is a bit messy. I find ggplot2 a bit easier to manipulate. You might try reproducing the plot the way you want it in ggplot and then using plotly's ggplotly function to convert it to an interactive version.